# Form field user can't be blank in rails (user not getting associated with form submission/model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models. A collection and a design.

Collections has_many designs and designs belong_to a collection.

Everything is working great except one thing. A user will create a collection, which gets associated with their user_id using current_user like so in my Collection controller

```
def create
  @collection = current_user.collections.build(collection_params)
end
```

this works great and the user_id will get associated to that. Unfortunately, my problem is creating the design within the collection. So A user created a collection, and goes to that collection page. If the user created that collection, a button will appear that says add designs. The add design form comes up and you can submit the design but no user_id is getting associated with the design created although the design does get associated with the collection.

Here is my Designs controller

```
def create
  @collection = current_user.collections.find(params[:collection_id])
  @design = @collection.designs.build(design_params)
end
```

I have these private before_actions

```
def set_design
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
  @design = @collection.designs.find(params[:id])
end

def find_collection
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
end
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Let me know if you need to see anything else like those models...

Thanks in advance guys/gals...have a good one

Comment: What is the relationship between user and designs? If it's a "has many through" collections, then you wouldn't need to associate a user_id directly with a design based on what you've shown.

Comment: Yep here is my User's model:
`has_many :designs, :through => :collections, dependent: :destroy`
`has_many :collections, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: So why does a design need a user_id (since it's already present in its parent collection)?

Comment: On a page i'm displaying all of the designs and Im trying to associated the user's name with that design.

Comment: Cool. How about an instance method in the Design class?... something like: `def user_name; collection.user.name; end`

Comment: @rossta delegate is here for you: `delegate :user_name, to: :user` if the relation `:user` exists and User responds to the instance method `.user_name`

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thanks, I know. I was starting with something less indirect.

Comment: Ha well the issue is still going back to the user_id/user not getting saved with a design creation! The reason i couldnt show the user's name on that page was because two of the designs didnt have a user attached (because i created them myself whereas the other ones were seeded) so those two were giving me the error.The problem goes back to the design creation.Its probably because I'm not calling current_user because I specified a current_user when i defined the `@collection` variable. Then when i create the `@desig`n variable I call the `@collection` variable which should include current_user

Comment: Does current_user.collections.designs not give you the designs scoped for that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have had this for the create method (this is the answer)

```
def create
  @collection = current_user.collections.find(params[:collection_id])
  @design = @collection.designs.new(design_params)
  @design.user = current_user
end
```